# Wireframe mode not really being wireframe (z-fighting occurs)

Tags: 3d-view, wireframe

Thing is, when I set viewport rendering to wireframe, I expect only edges to be rendered, not faces.
And this is true until two faces overlap - then I experience z-fighting.

I would really, really prefer this not to happen.

Here you can see two cubes, partially overlapping each other.

[image]

Comment: If you don't want that to happen, then avoid overlapping faces.

Comment: There are situations when I NEED to have overlapping faces. That's when working with maps. I used an example with cubes because it is clear. I wish Blender was rendering wireframe mode properly.

Comment: If you have overlapping texture maps then use overlapping UVs, Overlapping geometry will create z-fighting not only in wireframe but in the render.

Comment: I'm not going to render these maps. It's more CAD-like work that I do, and it's bound to have overlapping objects, for the sake of calculations and other stuff. I use CAD-style Transform addon and noticed that it has problems with snapping when faces overlap. I think if I could somehow totally get rid of face display and have pure edges on the screen, snapping might work properly and also visual response would be clearer.

Comment: Not sure if this is going to help, but if you make one of the objects a bit small, like in the cube example one cube size = 1 and the other cube size =0.999, you will see just edges

Comment: But then I will lose precision that I need like air. And still I will have problem with snapping.

Comment: Any known solutions?